# Update single field in several rows (C#, LINQ to SQL)

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have this table MyTable in my SQL Server database (simplified):

- id (primary key, identity),
- status (int),
- expires (datetime)
- notes (ntext)

I need to update `status` for all the rows where `status` is equal to 1 and the `expires` is less than the current time.

For testing purposes, there's a single entry in MyTable: [id=1, status=1, expires='2017.08.25. 21:17:28', notes='bla bla bla']

This is the code I'm using:

```
linqTable.Where(r => r.status == 1 && 
                     r.expires != null && 
                     r.expires < DateTime.Now)
         .ToList()
         .ForEach(r => r.status = 7);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I stumbled upon puzzling error at `db.SubmitChanges()`:

> The data types ntext and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator

Enabling the SQL statement logging showed what's going on under the hood:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable]
SET [status] = @p4
WHERE ([id] = @p0) AND ([status] = @p1) AND ([expires] = @p2) AND ([notes] = @p3)
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- @p1: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- @p2: Input DateTime (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [2017.08.25. 21:17:28]
-- @p3: Input NVarChar (Size = 4000; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [bla bla bla]
-- @p4: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [7]
```

Turned out the error was caused because I have incorrect type for the `ntext` column. But that's not the real issue here. The SQL statement generated by LINQ is very inefficient:

- it selects the record by querying for all the columns, what a nonsense, when using only the primary key column would be enough! I have declared that `id` is the primary key column
- I have to update only a single column, for multiple records. There should be no update for single records

I was expecting a query like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].MyTable
SET [status] = @p1
WHERE status = @p0 AND expires IS NOT NULL AND expires < GETDATE()
-- @p0: 1
-- @p1: 7
```

Is it possible to achieve such efficient SQL statement generation?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Also: Linq-to-SQL was never intended as a production ORM - it was merely a proof-of-concept for the LINQ technology. If you're serious about using an ORM for your production work, you should check out Entity Framework instead.

Comment: I wasn't aware that Linq-to-SQL is considered unstable for production environment. Anyway, my problem does not lie in the (fixable) string type, it's about what syntax should be used to get more efficient SQL queries.

Comment: where did the "bla bla bla" text come from? I doubt it was just there.

Comment: I edited the post to explain where it comes from. It's just the value of notes field for that particular entry.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no (out of the box) batch update in Linq-2-sql. There are some implementations like 
https://terryaney.wordpress.com/2008/04/14/batch-updates-and-deletes-with-linq-to-sql/

"it selects the record by querying for all the columns, what a nonsense, when using only the primary key column would be enough"

-> i do not think this will have a lot of impact on the efficiency. It is the update-per-record that is the expensive one